# Possible to Check if Azure AD SSO passes if user went through MFA in custom web app?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I wanted to know if there is a way for a custom developed web app to tell if an Azure AD SSO also had MFA. Ultimately, I'm trying to block access to a website if there was no MFA during the SSO process. I would essentially be creating a multi-tenanted application. Their documentation doesn't offer anything in this regard, and I know that MFA status isn't available via Graph yet, so I can't check if the user even has it enabled or enforced yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tokens are your web app receiving? For example with JWT tokens the amr (authentication mechanism reference) claim can be checked for the MFA claim. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks, I also found that as well. However, I've noticed that the amr claim is sometimes inaccurate, especially if you're using a third-party mfa provider like duo

Comment: That's expected as duo integration is considered a custom control. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/controls#known-limitations known limitations section explains that the integration will not satisfy MFA requirements. I guess it can be confusing for those that see Duo as a MFA vendor and expect that claim to be in the token :)

Comment: Custom controls is changing as per https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/upcoming-changes-to-custom-controls/ba-p/1144696# . So this Duo based MFA session may be something you can detect in the future via amr claims.